# Mongodb query with regex

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am learning python with mongodb in tornado.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566fb466d82f0769fbb0fb10"),
    "Pid" : "1",
    "Registration" : "1234",
    "Date" : "11-11-2015",
    "status" : "booked"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566fb47cd82f0769fbb0fb11"),
    "Pid" : "1",
    "Registration" : "1234",
    "Date" : "13-11-2015",
    "status" : "AOs"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566fb48bd82f0769fbb0fb12"),
    "Pid" : "1",
    "Registration" : "1234",
    "Date" : "14-11-2015",
    "status" : "NA"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("566fb4a3d82f0769fbb0fb13"),
    "Pid" : "1",
    "Registration" : "1234",
    "Date" : "16-12-2015",
    "status" : "AOr"
}
```

if I am  passing the month and year only ,I need the entire record of the given  month and year.

I tried doing this:

```
db.cal.aggregate({$project:{"monthyear": {$substr: ["$Date",0,2]}}})
```

the output is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566fb466d82f0769fbb0fb10"), "monthyear" : "11" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566fb47cd82f0769fbb0fb11"), "monthyear" : "13" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566fb48bd82f0769fbb0fb12"), "monthyear" : "14" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("566fb4a3d82f0769fbb0fb13"), "monthyear" : "16" }
```

but I need the below output:

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("566fb4a3d82f0769fbb0fb13")
  "Pid" : "1",
  "Registration" : "1234",
  "Date" : "16-12-2015",
  "status" : "AOr"

  }
```

Please, help

Comment: Why you are not using BSON Date type to store dates? Can you change format now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
db.cal.find({"Date":{"$regex":"12-2015"}})
```

Comment: when i find the values cal = db.cal.find({"Pid": Pid, "Registration": Reg, "Monthyear": {'$regex': "12-2015"}})
            for document in (yield cal.to_list(length=100)):
                data.append(document)
            print("data calendar", data)
            #info.info({"calendar": data, "statuscode": 1})
            return[{"cal": data, "statuscode": 1}]

Comment: but am getting no values

Comment: `find` returns cursor, so iterate it `for item in cursor: print item`